# Grouping multiple instances in a dataframe by 15 minute increments R

Tags: r

There are a lot of questions that want the data grouped by 15' by they are only doing it on a single column. Is there a generic function to transform the entire data table? I'm an R newbie and I can't figure it out.

My data set looks like the following

```
>>DF2[c(1:6), c(1:5)]
              Group.1   Station1 Station2 Station3 Station4
2018-09-25 10:01:00  2.37            5.1     2.263          0.737
2018-09-25 10:06:00  2.22            3.8     2.389          0.722
2018-09-25 10:11:00  1.94            6.2     3.389          0.500
2018-09-25 10:15:00  2.79            3.1     2.316          0.211
2018-09-25 10:20:00  2.25            3.5     2.700          0.450
2018-09-25 10:25:00  8.00            9.3    13.050          1.150
```

The `Group.1` column was generated with the following command `DF2$Group.1 <- strptime(DF2$Group.1, "%H:%M")`

Now, I would like to get the averages for all the stations in 15' increments. But time data in R are giving me a headache.
I'm looking for an output like the following:

```
Group.1   Station1 Station2 Station3 Station4
10:00:00-10:15:00  2.17    5.03     2.68   1.959
10:15:00-10:30:00  4.34    5.3      6.02   1.811
```

When I was unable to understand the different approaches described in different threads i tried doing it manually with for-loops but that proved an even bigger obstacle. I'm sure because R is R there has to be a one-liner that can do this sort of computation. Any help please?